# Find all the child node of specific value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, search, xmlnode

```
<main>
  <myself>
    <pid>1</pid>
    <name>abc</name>
  </myself>
  <myself>
    <pid>2</pid>
    <name>efg</name>
  </myself>
</main>
```

that is my XML file named simpan. I have two button. next and previous. What i want to do is, all the info will shows off on the TextBox when the user click the button. The searching node will be based on the pid.

Next button will adding 1 value of pid (let's say pid=2) and it will search on the node that have the same value of pid=2. it also will show the name for the pid=2. (showing name=abc)

Same goes to the previous button where it will reduce 1value of pid (pid=1).

Does anybody knows how to do this?

//-------------EDIT------------------

thanks to L.B, im trying to use his code. however i got an error.

[image]

is my implementation of code correct?

```
private void previousList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pid = 14;

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\Fatty\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\simpan.xml");

        var name = xDoc.Descendants("myself")
                    .First(m => (int)m.Element("PatientID") == pid)
                    .Value;

        textETA.Text = name;
        ////////////////////


    }
```

Comment: Put the caret on `XDocument.Parse` and press F1 then read the documentation, especially the argument description.

Comment: Call XDocument.Parse() with an XML string, use XDocument.Load() with a filename.

Answer (score 2):

```
int pid = 2;
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //Load

var name = xDoc.Descendants("myself")
            .First(m => (int)m.Element("pid") == pid)
            .Element("name")
            .Value;
```

Comment: i got an error. see at my post. i have post together with the error

Comment: @Sarabrown to load from file use load method of xdocument. Also see the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `XPath` to list all `Myself` tags, then look for what you want using a simple `Linq` command:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "file1.xml");
        var resNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//myself");
        XmlNode res = null;
        var val = textBox1.Text;

        var item = from XmlNode x in resNodes
                   select x;

        foreach (var nodP in item) {
            foreach (XmlNode nod in nodP.ChildNodes) {
                if (nod.InnerText == val) {
                    res = nodP;
                }
            }
        }

        if (res == null)
            // not found!
            ;
        else
            // show the result
            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me old fashioned but you could use an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx), for example:

```
string xml =
    @"<main>
        <myself>
            <pid>1</pid>
            <name>abc</name>
        </myself>
        <myself>
            <pid>2</pid>
            <name>efg</name>
        </myself>
      </main>";

using System.Xml;

....

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
// Replace "2" in the string below with the desired pid
XmlNode xmlNode = 
    xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("myself/name[../pid=2]");
// xmlNode contains the <name>efg</name> XmlElement. For example:
string name = xmlNode.Value;
```

If it can match multiple nodes, for example there could be multiple `<myself>` elements with a child element `<pid>` set to 2, use the following instead:

```
foreach(XmlNode xmlNode in 
    xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("myself/name[../pid=2]"))
{
    // xmlNode contains the matching <name> element
}
```

In both cases, the value can be extracted from the [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) using the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx) property.

Comment: may i ask what should i put in foreach (XmlNode xn in xmlNode)? if i want to appear the xmlNode in the textName.Text?

Comment: I have added another case in the answer if it could match multiple elements.

Comment: im assume i should put this in the foreach >> textETA.Text = xmlNode; but it said that the cannot convert system.xml.xmlnode to string.

Comment: Use the Value property of XmlNode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx for help on XmlNode.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void previousList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pid = 14;

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\HDAdmin\Documents\Fatty\SliceEngine\SliceEngine\bin\Debug\simpan.xml");

    var name = xDoc.Root
                   .Descendants("myself")
                   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("pid")
                   .Value
                   .Equals(pid.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                   .Element("name")
                   .Value;

    textETA.Text = name;
}
```

Comment: isnt that is my original codes?which that is the exact problem?

Comment: U use `XDocument.Parse()` and parsing file path, that's why U get that error. To get xDoc from file U should use `XDocument.Load()`. I didn't check the implementation of query, I just explained why you get error U asked for.

Comment: owh i see..thank you. i dont noticed it first. but thanks for the explanation again.

Comment: @sarabrown, see my updates, I suggest I fixed your name query. Well, at least, it works fine for me on .Net 4.5.

Comment: im using microsoft visual studio 2010. why it said that CultureInfo does not exist?

Comment: @sarabrown, add `using System.Globalization;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class simpman
{

    private static XElement root = XElement.Load("Simpman.xml");

    public static string GetItem(int index)
    {
        XElement item =
        (from element in root.Elements("myself")
        where (int)element.Element("pid") == index
        select element.Element("name")).SingleOrDefault();

        return item != null ? item.Value : "Please check the Index";
    }
}
```

Initialize a static `itemIndex` to 1 and use it further like `itemIndex++` (for Next) and `itemIndex--` (for Prev).

Answer (score 0):

`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(rootXMLPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            doc.Load(fs);
            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;`

`nodeName = "/main/myself";`

`var child1 = node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName).ChildNodes[0].FirstChild.InnerXml;
var child2 = node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName).ChildNodes[0].LastChild.InnerXml;
var child3 = node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName).ChildNodes[1].FirstChild.InnerXml;
var child4 = node.SelectSingleNode(nodeName).ChildNodes[1].LastChild.InnerXml;`